# Unable to access site after change from lagecy to claims based auth

Tags: claims-based-auth, access-denied

I have changed my web application from legacy to Claims based authentication. Now when I access the site I get:

> You are not authorized to view this site.....send a message to administrator to get access to the site...

I have tried to find an error in the logfiles, but finds nothing. The user that I log in with has full access rights on the web application.

In the IIS logs i find AccesDenied for my account..

Does anyone have a suggestion for me where to look for a solution?

I have added the superuseraccount and superreaderaccount and the account has got full acces to the database, so it has to be another problem...

Comment: I have added the superuseraccount and the account has got full acces to the database, so it has to be another problem...

Comment: Did you do MigrateUsers? Legacy user permissions no longer apply after conversion unless you migrate permissions to claims accounts or explicitly grant permission to claims accounts.

Comment: Have you completed all of the steps mentioned in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx to complete the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Most times this problem is caused by wrong formatted object-cache-accounts.

- Classic-Format: domain\username
- Claims-Format: i:0#.w|domain\username

Please make sure your cache-accounts are set to **claims**-format in:

- WebApplication User Policy
- `$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]` and
  `$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]`

Reference: [Configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx)